# How to insert into sybase table querying the same table

Tags: sybase

I want to insert in a table some different values for the already existing records there. I am using this command.

```
 insert into UserPnlCentre(userId,pnlCentreId,createdUser) values(select userId from UserPnlCentre where pnlCentreId!=4,4,'Migration')
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: when you use "values" keyword, you have to put exact single value rather than result.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
insert into UserPnlCentre (
        userId
        , pnlCentreId
        , createdUser
)
select  userId
        , 4
        , 'Migration'
from    UserPnlCentre
where   pnlCentreId != 4
```

Comment: This gives me the duplicate index error                                                  Attempt to insert duplicate key row in object 'UserPnlCentre' with unique index 'userPnlCentreIdx'

Comment: I have only transformed your insert. check for the columns in unique index and eliminate the duplicate from the insert script above